# I can't get rid of russian language in OS interface

Tags: kubuntu, 21.04, locale

I set up my kubuntu 21.04 with the English interface by default, cause I prefer the original version, but with russian regional settings (date, currency etc). As the result of some experiments I've got the following picture: English US is the only language installed, but the whole interface is in Russian [here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a03vS.png)

Locale's output also contains only russian:
`$ locale`

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Though contents of cat `/etc/default/locale` look correct

```
#  File generated by update-locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
```

`# update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
doesn't help either.

What am I doing wrong?.. No scripts in my home directory set or change LANG variable.

WMBR, George Hazan

Comment: 1. Yes, some KDE specific configuration file in your `$HOME` has most likely been changed. 2. No, your `/etc/default/locale` is not correct either. In particular `LC_MESSAGES` is set to a Russian locale. 3. You messed it up through your experiments. Maybe some Kubuntu user can give you a hand. Or you should consider a re-install.

Comment: @mikewhatever yes, I can forcibly specify LANG=en_US.UTF-8 in /etc/environment, and it would help, but I wanted to solve this problem using UI tools, cause I hadn't issued any command-line calls to modify my locale.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson
1. which concrete file might that be?
2. well, at least ssh-add gives me messages in English, but I'll try to make some additional observations
3. ok, I'll try to dig more recommendations from mikewhatever's article, there're some interesting ideas about locale files recreation. No, reinstall is not possible in my case

Comment: at least 
>sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales 
doesn't help me... The problem is evidently in the conflict between /etc/default/locale and locale's output, I just tested some remote Ubuntu installations at my servers, everything is ok there.